# WFFM 8.1 upgrade - AssessSecurityRisk is obsolete

Tags: wffm

We are in process of upgrading from WFFM 8.0 to WFFM 8.1 and when rebuilding our code I received an error on a class we built which inherits AssessSecurityRisk.

> [deprecated] class Sitecore.Form.Submit.AssessSecurityRisk
>   'AssessSecurityRisk' is obsolete

```cs
public class AssessSecurityRiskCustom: Sitecore.Form.Submit.AssessSecurityRisk
{
...
}
```

Any thoughts please pass on.

Thx in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existing `Form Verification/Assess Security Risk` action still points to the old `Sitecore.Form.Submit.AssessSecurityRisk` which is marked `Obsolete`. Normally `Obsolete` messages are marked with "Please use X instead"...

Given that the out of the box `Assess Security Risk` Action is still using the obsolete class you are probably ok to continue to use this for the moment (until the next upgrade at least). I would still raise a support ticket and ask for clarification though.

**EDIT:**

In Sitecore 8.2 the `Assess Security Risk` item has no `Class` or `Assembly` items set, which suggests the item has been left in as a legacy for existing forms but is no longer used. It may be that [the form submissions are encoded by default now](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/568572), but worth verifying with Support.

The verification was removed in [WFFM 2.4 rev 151103](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,4/Release%20Notes.aspx), which would have been rolled into the later WFFM versions.

> The default Assess Security Risk verification had worked incorrectly for the list fields. This verification can now be removed from the form. (66912)